# How to add an underline and link attribute to the same portion of text?

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a UITextView and want to add some underlined links within the text, the code is as follows:

```
    subText.text = NSLocalizedString("VC_COMMON_SUBSCRIBE_FULL_TEXT", comment: "")
    let theString = subtext.attributedText?.mutableCopy(with: nil) as! NSMutableAttributedString
    let tcRange = theString.mutableString.range(of: NSLocalizedString("VC_COMMON_SUBSCRIBE_TERMS_TEXT", comment: ""))
    let ppRange = theString.mutableString.range(of: NSLocalizedString("VC_COMMON_SUBSCRIBE_PRIVACY_TEXT", comment: ""))
    theString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: Config.termsAndConditionsURL(), range: tcRange)
    theString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: Config.privacyPolicyURL(), range: ppRange)
    theString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: tcRange)
    theString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: ppRange)
    subtext.attributedText = theString
```

The problem with this code is that when run the parts of the text which contain the link are not visible (though the links are selectable, even though its text can't be seen) If I comment out the link attributes and just use the underline attributes then the text appears with underlining as expected.
Why is adding the link attribute causing the text to not show?

I tried using a UILabel instead of a UITextView and it displays correctly, however the links don't work in this case, even though the UILabel has userInteractionEnabled set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the localized strings with my own strings and the links with dummy links. This code shows the text view properly:

```
let subText = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
subText.text = NSLocalizedString("These are the terms. This is our privacy policy", comment: "")
let theString = subText.attributedText?.mutableCopy(with: nil) as! NSMutableAttributedString
let tcRange = theString.mutableString.range(of: NSLocalizedString("terms", comment: ""))
let ppRange = theString.mutableString.range(of: NSLocalizedString("privacy policy", comment: ""))
theString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: "https://google.com", range: tcRange)
theString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: "https://google.com", range: ppRange)
theString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: tcRange)
theString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: ppRange)
subText.attributedText = theString
```

Image from a playground quicklook:

[image]

It appears that you are using constants like `NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName`. They have been renamed to `NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle` and so on.

Comment: Its swift 3, not swift 4 that the code is in thats why its using NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName. I can try upgrading the code to Swift 4 to see if anything changes.

Comment: @Gruntcakes You should've tagged it [tag:swift3]. Anyway, does it work if you used my particular strings and links in Swift 3 (with the names changed)? And if that doesn't work, try Swift 4.

Comment: I've updated the project to Swift 4. However your code produces the same as I'm seeing - the difference being I didn't run in a playground, I replaced subText with a UITextView IBOutlet.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of how the text view is displayed? @Gruntcakes

Comment: I created a new template project and with that its ok. There's something else about my project interfering with it somewhere somehow,

Comment: @Gruntcakes I suggest commenting out some parts of your project and see if it works. This way you might be able to find what is causing this behaviour. Still, I'm quite interested in how the text view is displayed as. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I've posted it, I think my issue must be some appearance protocol value being set somewhere. Looking.